# Adding a header file for all files in a directory

Tags: c

I have a directory with lots of C files. For each of these C files, I need to add the line `#include config.h`. Is there a way to avoid doing this manually?

I'm thinking that maybe there is a neat way to tell the preprocessor to do that, or maybe pass a well-constructed flag to the linker. How can I get all files in a directory to "include" the same header file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either use `-include` switch

```
$ cat foo.c
int main(void) {
    printf("%s\n", "ohai there o/");
    return 0;
}
$ gcc -include stdio.h foo.c
```

or write a script that will insert that include for you automatically

in these examples editing *`.c`* files, and adding the include in the very *1st line* of the file.

assuming **bash** shell, **GNU** `sed` :

```
while read -r; do
    sed -i '1i #include "config.h"' "$REPLY"
done < <(find /path/to/project/dir -type f -name "*.c")
```

or with something **POSIX**

```
find /path/to/project/dir -type f -name "*.c" | while read -r file; do
    ed "$file" <<EOF
0a
#include "config.h"
.
wq
EOF
done
```